# How to forward method call to another object in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I want to forward method call of one object to another object. Is there any way or hack in Laravel to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has built in trait for this purpose. The trait takes care of forwarding the method calls as well as catching possible exceptions.

```
<?php 

use Illuminae\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls;

class Farwarder 
{
    use ForwardsCalls;

    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        return $this->forwardCallTo(
          \app(SomeOtherClass), $method, $arguments  
        );
    }
}
```